# In Marvel's 1990 Captain America film what did Steve Rogers' metal star represent?

Tags: marvel, captain-america

In Marvel's [Captain America film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103923/) what did Steve Rogers' metal star represent?

[image]

It is pictured in his hand above. I didn't get to see the entire movie but it didn't look like a rank or something from his uniform. More like a police badge.

Comment: It appears to be a US Army [Silver Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Star) medal.

Comment: @Valorum Feel free to put it as an answer. I kick myself for the screenshot resolution because I can't see an inner silver star, but the original resolution was pretty bad too (it's from YouTube). It makes sense, the Army was his branch.

Comment: I'm trying to find a better image or a quote/reference from the movie.

Comment: @Valorum I found an alleged script but you have to have a Scribd account to view it https://www.scribd.com/document/274668305/Captain-America-Awfully-Good-Movies-Script

Comment: Which Captain America film is this? The one from 1990? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103923/

Comment: @DCShannon Yea, the first one

Comment: There were actually two of them in '79.

Comment: @DCShannon Well that was a TV special, but yes 1990

Comment: Added an IMDB link to identify the movie. Should we add a tag for the specific movie? There are ones for each of the recent MCU movies. Also, +1

Comment: @Hack-R - That script is only three pages long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the movie never says exactly what the medal is. I *think* Valorum's comment is correct that it's a Silver Star. Whatever it was, it was not Steve's but his father's. [Around the 7 minute mark](https://youtu.be/6-MlQHU-n8M?t=410) Steve's mom gives the medal to Steve:

> Mom: "I want you to promise me you'll never take this off."
>
> Steve: "Dad's Medal."

The implication in the scene is the medal was awarded posthumously to Steve's father for actions on Guadalcanal.